# Symfony2, How do I perform a database retrieve in Doctrine with a drop down list form?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form that will perform a search action with a drop down list of choices of category to search. The drop down list are subjects to search by. So:

Search by: 
1) Invoice #
2) Tracking #
3) BL #

Then enter in the value and submit to search.

I have my form:

```
// src Bundle\Form\Type\SearchType.php

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('kind', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'invoice' => 'Invoice #',
                'trackingno' => 'Tracking Number'
                'blno' => 'BL #',
            ),
            'label' => 'Search by: '
        ))
            ->add('value', 'text', array(
                'label' => false
            ))
            ->add('Submit','submit');
}
```

With this function in the controller:

```
public function getForm() {

    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchType(), array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('search_view'),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ) );

    return $form;

}
```

With the action going to 'search_view' function:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/results/", name="search_view")
 */
public function searchAction(Request $request) {
    $kind = $request->get('kind');
    $value = $request->get('value');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $findCfs = $em->getRepository("CFSBundle:Cfs")
            ->searchCfs($kind, $value);

    return $this->render("CFSBundle:Search:index.html.twig", array(
            'results' => $findCfs
        ));

}
```

My problem is I do not where to go to perform the database retrieval base on the category. This is what I have in the repository:

```
 public function searchCfs($kind, $value) {
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT
                 c.blno, m.ctrno, c.carrier, m.refno
            FROM
                CFSBundle:Cfs c
            LEFT JOIN
                cfs.refno m
            WHERE
                :kind LIKE :value
            ')->setParameter("kind", $kind)
            ->setParameter("value", $value);

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course this isn't working. I thought about creating different queries for each category and have the conditions submit according to its category, but I was wondering if there was one simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise using the `QueryBuilder` class when writing a query such as this, rather than writing DQL directly.

You could then do something like the following in your repository:

```
const KIND_INVOICE_NO = 'invoice';
const KIND_TRACKING_NO = 'tracking';
const KIND_BL_NO = 'blno';

public function searchCfs($kind, $value) {
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.blno, m.ctrno, c.carrier, m.refno')
        ->leftJoin('cfs.refno', 'm');

    if ($kind === self::KIND_INVOICE_NO) {
        $queryBuilder->where('c.invoiceno = :queryValue');
    } elseif ($kind === self::KIND_TRACKING_NO) {
        $queryBuilder->where('m.ctrno = :queryValue')
    } elseif ($kind === self::KIND_BL_NO) {
        $queryBuilder->where('c.blno = :queryValue')
    }

    $queryBuilder->setParameter('queryValue', $value);

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: would I need to set parameter for :queryValue to $value?